# Anyone can explain the syntax for the boost tuple library?

Tags: c++, boost

When I use `Boost.Tuple`, I have to use some syntax like:

```
result.get<0>()
```

It looks very unfamiliar to me. Usually `<>` contains a typename, why does it use an `int` here?

Comment: Using integers as template arguments is perfectly valid in C++.

Comment: It uses the int to give a number... It's about as complicated as it looks.

Comment: why not use something like result.get<int>(1)?

Comment: You should actually use the free function `get<0>(result)`, because the member function is not supported by all compilers (which probably don't implement templates correctly enough for it to be possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason they use the syntax `result.get<0>()` is that each element of the tuple can have a different type, and this syntax is the simplest way in C++ to let the compiler do the right thing with types.

If the function were just plain `get(0)`, all elements of the tuple would have to have the same type, because there's no way to have one untemplated `get` function that returns several different types.

Something like `result.get<int>(0)` could theoretically work, but it's more verbose, and introduces a potential source of error--what if the 0th element wasn't an `int` at all? Worse still, you'd  only be able to catch this error at runtime. The syntax used in Boost is plain and simple--the only way you can possibly screw it up is to specify an invalid index, and that can be caught at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

What goes between `<>` can be types. It can also be integers. It can be quite a lot of things, actually. Template parameters can be typenames, but they can also be compile-time constant values.

This declares a template function that takes a type:

```
template<typename T> void foo();
```

This one takes a compile-time integer:

```
template<int I> void foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with Template MetaProgramming (TMP) this is a fairly familiar syntax. But if you don't want to get into the black magic of compile-time programming then all you should worry about is that the template parameter is the index into the tuple